# MsAccess SQL: how to prevent duplicates from Select query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a Select query (many fields and some calculated fields) that Joins over many tables with a non-trivial Where clause and Order By clause. Depending on the user filters, it can return duplicate records based on the ID of one of the Joined tables. I would like to eliminate all result rows that have a duplicate `table1.ID` value.

Example:

```
Select a.fld1, b.fld2, c.fld3, d.fld4 from (((tablea join tableb on a.x=b.x)
 join tablec on c.x=a.x) join tabled on d.x=a.x where blah-blah.
```

This will return:

```
a.fld1, b.fld2, c.fld3, d.fld4
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 21, 3, 4
2, 2, 3, 4
2, 22, 3, 4
```

I want to eliminate extra rows with duplicate a.fld1 values. b.fld2 will be different and I don't care which of those records gets left out. But I do need at least one value from b.fld2 for other lookup purposes.

I can't seem to figure out a good way to do this.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: This is hard to tell without knowing your queries and schemas ut do you know about SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Yes - thanks. I know about DISTINCT. Maybe I don't understand how to make that work when I am selecting many fields from many tables, some are calculated and some are 'table.*'. There is nothing unique about my schema; just tables and fields.

Comment: You see some of the fields returned are different, and I don't care about them, I just need to exclude duplicates based on one field from one table.

Comment: If you are returning columns you dont care about but are not unique, then you need to either specify which of the multiple values you do want, or leave the columns out and use Distinct as suggested. SQL has no idea which columns *you* think are important, its interested in the complete result set.

Comment: Hi, I do need those columns under certain circumstances, I just don't care if they are value1 or value2. So DISTINCT would still return duplicates for table1.ID. The key is not having duplicates for table1.ID. So how would one go about that? Thanks.

Comment: This question really needs an [mcve]. Yes, it will be work to create one, but I don't see how we could help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps I might normally like to write this proposed solution as a comment, but at this time I still need a higher reputation to be able to write comments.)

In just looking at your output it seems like you could just take the SQL you have and use it all as a subquery in a new SQL statement that groups on the first field (and also get the first value or the lowest value or whatever you deem appropriate for the other fields as long as it is OK if the data in different fields in one resulting row may come from different records)...